# Unable to render external images in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

New to javascript, please help me to render external images in html2canvas script. Do I have to use `useCORS`? If yes, where? I have tried rendering images from css and html tags too but its not reflecting.

Also console error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

```js
const elm = document.querySelector(".convert");
html2canvas(elm).then(function(canvas) {
  document.querySelector(".result");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  let cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
  let a = document.querySelector(".a");
  a.href= cvs.toDataURL();
  a.download="example.png";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem

```dart
html2canvas(this.PrintOrderID.nativeElement, {
  scale: 2,
  width: mywindow!.innerHeight,
  height: mywindow!.innerWidth,
  useCORS: true,
  allowTaint : true
}).then((canvas) => {
  mywindow!.document.body.appendChild(canvas);
})
```

Comment: The question is marked javascript but your answer appears to use Dart. Providing an answer in a different programming language isn't helpful.

Comment: @Ouroborus, Not necessarily. It can provide logical guide to accomplishing the equivalent. Obviously there may be issues with syntax, built-ins, etc... that have to be taken into consideration.